# Geometric View of First-Order Quasilinear PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Theorem 1 in page 4 of the book [**Numerical Solution of Partial Differential Equations in Science and Engineering**](https://books.google.com/books?id=WhyUYUlU7BEC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Numerical%20Solution%20of%20Partial%20Differential%20Equations%20in%20Science%20and%20Engineering&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjIhbeynOnMAhVEDiwKHfd6AW8Q6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=Numerical%20Solution%20of%20Partial%20Differential%20Equations%20in%20Science%20and%20Engineering&f=false) by *L. Lapidus*:

The general solution of the quasilinear PDE
$$a(x,y,u)u_x + b(x, y,u)u_y = c(x, y,u),$$
is given by
$$G(v,w)=0,$$
where $G$ is an arbitrary function and where $v(x, y, u) = c_1$, and $w(x,y,u)=c_2$ form a solution of the equations
$$\frac{dx}{a}=\frac{dy}{b}=\frac{du}{c}.$$

My question is how can I prove this theorem?

In that book, it explains how can interpret quasilinear PDEs geometrically, but I can't understand how to obtain $\frac{dx}{a}=\frac{dy}{b}=\frac{du}{c}$.

Thanks in advance for any explanation or clarification about this theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $u(x,y)$ is a solution then
$$du=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}dy$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=\frac{du-\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}dx}{dy}$$
The equation becomes
$$a\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+b\frac{du-\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}dx}{dy}=c$$
$$a\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}dy+bdu-b\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}dx=cdy$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\bigg(ady-bdx\bigg)=cdy-bdu$$
The equation holds for
$$(1) ady-bdx=0\Rightarrow \frac{dy}{b}=\frac{dx}{a}$$
$$(2) cdy-bdu=0\Rightarrow \frac{du}{c}=\frac{dy}{b}$$

Comment: Thanks @Occupy for your question, can i ask one another question?
How G is answer of the pdes? i mean a construction proof.

Comment: @user626 You can check the Cauchy problem to get more insight.

Comment: @ccupy-gezi I read Cauchy problem but i can't find relation between my question and it.